# Making the mouse coordinates take the center of a frame as Origin-Java

Tags: java, mousemotionlistener

How can I make MouseMotionListener reads (0,0) in the center of a frame instead of the default top left position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Instead you translate the Point returned in your program's model.

Create a method, `Point convert(Point p)` where you translate (and scale if need be), the Point on the *view* that the MouseMotionListener returns, to give the Point in the program's *model*.